# Converting linkedin oauth v1 api keys to v2 api key?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api, api-key

I have some code that will let the user login via linked in using the oauth v1 api. That returns two keys back to me which are user token and user secret.

I have tried using them with the v2 api but it seems as though it wants oauth2_access_token.

Is there any way to use the user token and user secret to make api calls?

If not is there a way to convert user token and user secret to the new oauth2_access_token needed for v2?

If not is there any way to have v2 check to see if the user has authenticated the app and return the new v2 key?

Answer (score 2):

If you have already setup OAuth v1 authentication successsfully, I would suggest you stick to it, as Linkedin will be supporting both authentication schemes moving forward. You can use all of the API functions with both authentications schemes. I don't see any reason to rewrite your authentication scheme.

Comment: How does one make api calls using the v1 OAuth tokens?

Comment: See here for OAuth 1.0 examples: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/making-api-call-oauth-token

Comment: Thanks that starting to lead down the correct path. Only down side is there is no example for php. Any idea how to do the raw requests using curl?

Comment: The above link no longer works, Does Linkedin still support API calls with OAuth 1.0, and are there any examples?